# how to add new properties into a user from the standart asp.net mvc users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm new in the asp.net mvc development and have a quastin about the standart user database which is created in all the mvc templates.

all users have e.g. a username and a email, but this is not enougth, i wanted to ask how can i add more properties like e.g. telephone number?

is there any tutorial where this is explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Membership provider oveview
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7
Answer for your question
http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/